# Windws - DNS for two NICs - one with hosted network

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, dns, network-adapter

Hi I have a PC that runs a small web app (wamp based) and invites the user to take it's smartphone to use it.

For that we use 2 wireless connections;
 - built-in: The wifi card with windows 'wireless hosted network'
 - an UTP cable from the PC to an access point with another wireless network (for 5Gzh band)

Perhaps interesting to note is that the built-in wifi is also used to connect to the internet (the wifi card can act as a client and ap at the same time)

The result looks like this:
- Wifi built in (access point) : SSID "network" - IP 192.168.173.1 (windows fixed + dhcp server initiated by windows)
- Access point (5GZ/UTP) : SSID "network 5GZ" - IP 192.168.173.2 (dhcp reserved in AP)
- Wifi client : any IP

Now a user has to open 192.168.173.1 on wifi "network" and 192.168.173.2 on wifi "network 5GZ" - for the same page, which causes lot's of confusion.

See schema:

[image]

I'm looking for a tool (or some code, have a background as C#/C++ developper) that allows you to create a local DNS server to achieve this;

> 192.168.173.1  demo.domain.com
>   192.168.173.2  demo.domain.com

If the user is not on the networks, a page on the internet 'demo.domain.com' will show them that they have to connect to the Wifi's.

If they go to demo.domain.com on one of the 2 wifi they should go to the local hosted page.

I've been experimenting with http://sourceforge.net/projects/dhcp-dns-server - without luck and wonder if there are (easy) ways to achieve this.

Any help?

Comment: So at present what (is anything) is hosting DNS on each subnet?

Comment: Currently no specific DNS software yet - btw Windows 7 (later 8) - no server edition

Comment: I would look at MaraDNS which you can bind to each interface IP for each adapter that way you have people who hit 192.168.173.1 resolve xxx to itself and the same for the other interface.. Here is a tutorial http://blog.mixu.net/2009/10/14/how-to-setup-a-lan-dns-server-using-maradns-under-windows-7/

Comment: CharlesH - thanks for the fast reply -- I will follow the tuturial and give it a try. Once tried, I will add a comment - many thanks

Comment: No worries, I won't put as answer because its more trial and error than an answer however if it works then I'll write it up for you to confirm it worked for you :)

Comment: I have to say, it was still some puzzling, required me to run 2 maraDNS instances at the same time, but it is working -- Many thanks CharlesH.

Comment: Glad you got it working, I'll pop this in answer if you could accept it that would be great! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look at MaraDNS which you can bind to each interface IP for each adapter that way you have people who hit 192.168.173.1 resolve xxx to itself and the same for the other interface.. Here is a tutorial blog.mixu.net/2009/10/14/

Please see comments for more information...